# Overriding Liferay's Document Library

Tags: java, liferay

Question asked in Liferay Forums post [here](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/72025213)

I'm trying to implement the most basic of Overrides on the Document Library.

When a user hits my document repo, I'd like to add some logic to alter the view. I figured that extending the [DLFileEntryLocalServiceWrapper](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs-all/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/impl/DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.html)
 this could be accomplished, as it has a `getDLFileEntries()` method.

Here's my Class

```
public class DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl extends DLFileEntryLocalServiceWrapper {

    public DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl(DLFileEntryLocalService dlFileEntryLocalService) {
        super(dlFileEntryLocalService);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public List<DLFileEntry> getDLFileEntries(int start, int end)
    throws com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException {

        System.out.println("GETTING DL FILE ENTRIES");
        return super.getDLFileEntries(start, end);
    }
}
```

In my liferay-hook.xml I have

```
<service>
    <service-type>com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLAppLocalService</service-type>
    <service-impl>com.liferay.custom.hook.DLAppLocalServiceImpl</service-impl>
</service>
<service>
    <service-type>com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryLocalService</service-type>
    <service-impl>com.liferay.custom.hook.DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl</service-impl>
</service>
```

However my System.out never prints - I've tried extending  DLAppLocalService and DLAppService as well, but no luck.

I also want to override methods when adding & updating file entries too - am I extending the correct classes?

Comment: What made you think that when you hit Document Repo, it calls this particular method? based on jsp code it uses `getFoldersAndFileEntriesAndFileShortcuts` method of DLAppServiceImpl. You may dive deep into the code

Comment: Provably my lack of understanding. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Say @PankajkumarKathiriya - where exactly did you grab that method name from & are you assuming this method is called whenever/wherever the documents are retrieved?

Comment: `portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\document_library\view_file_entries.jspf` this is the file where I looked into. If you are working on Document and Media portlet then study source code code that portlet which will give you exact idea